# Disable aws amplify facebook/Google login only for react web app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, aws-amplify

I am building a react based web app and a react native based mobile app based on the same AWS Amplify backend. I want to enable the facebook and google login only for mobile based app but disable for the web app. How can I implement this?